# Which material properties determine whether it is best cut with a serrated edge?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, material-science, popular-science

Among foods, it is beneficial to use a serrated knife to cut bread and cooked meat, while a serrated edge has less benefit for other items. And then serrated saws are also helpful for cutting wood (both in logging and carpentry). Can we explain such observations with a simple model involving various material properties?

For example, bread knives are serrated because the plasticity of bread means that non-serrated knives simply squeeze the bread. However, the flesh of a peeled ripe banana has high plasticity, yet serrations are unnecessary. But an unpeeled banana requires a serrated knife due to the fibrous peeling.

Answer (score 2):

Materials can be placed on a scale of more brittle (and less ductile) and more ductile (and less brittle).

Brittle materials can be hard, but nevertheless breaks easily with an impact as is the case of glass. Ductile materials are softer, allowing scratching and penetration, they deforms but don't easily break.

A serrated knife makes a lot of small impacts, what is efficient to break the brittle bread shell. It is the same principle for the impact mode in a driller to make a hole in concrete.